# Finding matching objects in array: array or object

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

I defined a class `My_Class`. One attribute of it is `type`: let's say `"A"`, `"B"`, or `"C"`. I created an array `my_ary` of instances of `My_Class`, and sorted it based on date, time, and other instance data. The items are in a specific sequence. I want to iterate over the array, and for each object of type `"A"`, find the next sequential item of type `"B"` that has not been paired with a type `"A"` item, then pair those two items. The item being paired must be the next subsequent up-paired type `"B"` object.

I can do this using a loop on the array:

```
(0...my_ary.length) do |idx|
   if (my_ary[idx].type=="A") then
      ...iterate array from idx+1 and find next available type "B", 
         "pair" it to item at idx, and make paired item unavailable 
         for further matching...
   end
end
```

Array elements 0..6 **before** pairing.  Each line is a My_Class object, not a Hash.  I used BRACKETs and hash-like key-value notation for each array element because I don't know how to properly represent an array of objects.

```
idx   data
0     [type:'A' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/1/2000' , ...other data...]
1     [type:'C' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/2/2000' , ...other data...]
2     [type:'A' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/5/2000' , ...other data...]
3     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/5/2000' , ...other data...]
4     [type:'A' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/6/2000' , ...other data...]
5     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/6/2000' , ...other data...]
6     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/8/2000' , ...other data...]
```

**after** pairing

```
idx   data
0     [type:'A' , pairedto:3 , pairedby:nil , '1/1/2000' , ...other data...]
1     [type:'C' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:nil , '1/2/2000' , ...other data...]
2     [type:'A' , pairedto:5 , pairedby:nil , '1/5/2000' , ...other data...]
3     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:0 , '1/5/2000' , ...other data...]
4     [type:'A' , pairedto:6 , pairedby:nil , '1/6/2000' , ...other data...]
5     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:2 , '1/6/2000' , ...other data...]
6     [type:'B' , pairedto:nil , pairedby:4 , '1/8/2000' , ...other data...]
```

I'd like to move some or all of the iteration, qualifying, searching, and pairing logic to the class definition.  *I want to emphasize that the data and operations are not that  significant - what I'm trying to do is discover ruby-centric or non-traditional approaches to iterating and classifying a collection of objects.  The actual code that does the work is irrelevant.*  For this problem, I see two opportunities:

i. Keep the array iterator in the main program but extend the class to allow an object to search the remaining objects in the array: For each type `"A"` item, find the next available type `"B"`, and pair itself to that object:

```
    (0...my_ary.length) do |idx| 
      if (my_ary[idx].type=="A") then my_ary[idx].pair_yourself(y_ary,idx) end 
    end
```

ii. Move the main program array iterator to a class method and combine with option 1. Let the class deal with everything. The main program says:

```
    My_Class.go_pair_all_items_in_array(my_ary)
```

Questions:

1. In method 2, is it fair to make `My_Class` responsible for iterating an array of unknown shape and form? It's assumed any array passed in will be of `My_Class` items or derived from that. I'm pretty sure there's a way for the Class method to determine if the array passed in contains elements derived from itself.
2. Any other non-traditional ways to do this? I know I could create a class just for the array and have it handle list iteration but that doesn't seem like enough of a mental challenge.

Comment: It is probably worth adding a short example of the pairing process start and end (with say 6 items total). I'd also assume there is an output structure required with the pairs accessible in some way? It took me some time to understand your question because you are assuming this is something unimportant - please add it, it will make things easier.

Comment: Your question is not bad, but it would be much better if you pared it down to include actual code for `My_Class` (simplified to match the example here), e.g. and stubbed out your array, and included the results you desire after calling it this method.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're a Java or C++ programmer because your thinking is class-centric.

The Ruby way is duck typing.  For classification pairing to work, you need only know if the items in a list `respond_to?` a `type` method and a `pairedby=`.  It would be pretty standard Ruby to implement this operation as a mix-in on arrays.

You should probably not split such simple functionality across two classes unless there is a need to access the inner function, i.e. `pair_with_next`.

One reason:  By splitting the function you pretty much doom yourself to O(n^2) performance when O(n) is trivial to obtain. Make one pass. Keep a queue of A indexes.  When you see a B, remove the head index from the queue.  That's the A that matches the current B.  Continue until complete.  If the queue is empty, assign nil for the matching A. Ruby arrays easily implement queues.

A mix-in would look like:

```
class Array
  def pairable_by_type?
    all? {|i| [:type, :pairedby=].all?{|t| i.respond_to? t } }
  end

  def pair_by_type(a='A', b='B')
    q = []
    each_with_index do |item, i|
      item.pairedby = nil  # clear previous pairing
      case item.type
        when a
          q << i
        when b
          item.pairedby = q.shift
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have not tested this, but it ought to be close.  You'd just say `my_ary.pair_by_type` to get the job done.  Also `my_ary.pairable_by_type?` would tell you it's doable.

This mix-in adds the pairing functionality to *all* arrays in the application.  Some may find this distasteful. To avoid it,

```
class Array
  def self.new_pairable
    ary = []  
    def ary.pair_by_type(a='A', b='B')
      q = []
      each_with_index do |item, i|
        item.pairedby = nil  # clear previous pairing
        case item.type
          when a
            q << i
          when b
            item.pairedby = q.shift
        end
      end
    end
    ary
  end
end
```

Now you can say `my_ary = Array.new_pairable` and then `my_ary.pair_by_type`.  But normally created arrays won't have the `pair_by_type` method.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I want to think there will be some kind of name collision between your mixin "Array" and the built-in "Array" class.  Why doesn't this occur?

Comment: @mnemotronic: Ruby allows you to "re-open" nearly all class and module definitions and add more to them at any time, there's no clash. Doing this to Ruby core classes is not always a great idea, but it can be very useful when there is a good design fit. It's also great fun for exploring the language.

Comment: @mnemotronic As Neil Slater said, Ruby is not Java or C++!  There is no problem with adding functionality to existing classes without the need to subclass.  This is the "mix-in" I mentioned.  I made an addition to show how you can avoid attaching the pairing behavior to all arrays if for some reason you find it undesirable to do so.